# :"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"b-2.ashiqxxxxxxxonaws.com:9092

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk, kafkajs

I am using `IAM Authentication` in my AWS MSK Cluster. but when I am trying to access the MSK broker using telnet , `telnet b-1.ashxxxx.xx74.cx.kafka.xx-southeast-1.amazonaws.com  9092`, its getting timeout error.`"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection timeout","broker":"b-2.ashique.et7l74.c3.kafka.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:9092"`

Answer (score 1):

Telnet won't return a kafkajs error message...

IAM authentication is not done on port 9092, but 9098 or 9198 depending on where your code runs

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/port-info.html